# SWIFT Property List: From TableView to DetailView plist

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, tableview, plist

First time using plist. just playing around to find some alternatives to using dictionary/arrays. I have the following tableview being populated by a plist.

[image]

### Plist Help

Can plist also allow me to click on individual items on the plist and display some data from the plist? or no? haven't really found anything on it yet. all help and tips are truly appreciated.

EXAMPLE of what I am trying to do:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIUnYwbtSDg

### TableViewController

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var tableData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TableData", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    
    tableData = dict!.objectForKey("AppleDevice") as! [String]
```

Comment: FYI: `plist` standard for *property* list, not priority list.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below screenshot.

[image]

As in screenshot just click on the .plist file -> Open As -> Property List which will show in property list manner which you had mentioned in video of YouTube.

**Update**

Please find the below example consider your .plist data:

```
let detailController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailViewController") as? DetailViewController

tableData = dict!.objectForKey("AppleDevice") as! [String]
detailController.detailInfo = tableData
```

You can take another view controller name instead of DetailViewController.

**In DetailViewController class :**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var detailInfo: [String]? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            print("Detail Information",detailInfo)

            //Now here you can display the data in any UI component like UITextView.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: Thanks for that. but I was meaning, how could i display that info in another screen e.g. TextView in another View Controller. @Ramkrishna

Comment: @ScarletEnvy : I had updated my answer please check it and if it will work for you then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode, just right click on the .plist file and select Open As -> Property List